# 403 forbidden error when using Spring boot - security

Tags: spring-boot, post

I'm getting `403 forbidden error` when using Spring boot security for basic authentication. I get this error when using the `POST` method.

My main class code is as follows,

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) 
    {
       return builder.sources(MyContext.class);
    }
```

Please suggest a solution for this. Thanks

Comment: Did GET work fine and problem with only for POST?

Comment: yes GET is working fine and the problem is there with POST

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*I get this error using Post method.*

Above line gives hint that the issue is due to [CSRF protection](https://spring.io/blog/2013/08/21/spring-security-3-2-0-rc1-highlights-csrf-protection/). If users will not be using your application in a web browser, then it is safe to disable CSRF protection. Otherwise you should ensure to include the CSRF token in the request.

To disable CSRF protection you can use the following:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http
     // ...
     .csrf().disable();
}
```

Refer [spring-security-csrf](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-csrf)

Comment: Can you tell what dependency needs to be added in pom for using HttpSecurity? I have added spring -boot starter security already

Comment: no need to add any dependency other than spring -boot starter security..just refer the link i attached at the end and search for how to disable csrf spring boot security.

Comment: I am getting error HttpSecurity cannot be resolved to a type and also not able to import one.

Comment: I am trying to use spring boot....so is it not the part of spring boot starter security?

Comment: it worked by disabling csrf but now I am not getting login page that I used for basic authentication.Can anyone suggest why?